# convert HH:MM:SS time format into total minutes in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I want to convert a time value, ex:

"02:12:43", into the total number of minutes

in this example the result should be 2*60+12+round(43)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 02:12:43 is in A1. In B1 put =ROUND(A1*24*60, 0) and format B1 as Plain Text.